# Retrieving the node value in Firebase Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase, and I'm having my database like this:

```
root:
   admin:
       uid1:
          some info
       uid2:
          some info
       ..
        ...
         ....
```

I want to get all the nodes value, only the `uid` value except `some info`. How can I retrieve this value? Basically what I'm trying to do is search for a particular `uid` in this particular child,so I was thinking of retrieving these values and compare it with my `uid`?

Any help, in any of the problem, would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it with REST you can just call root/admin/.json to get the child value. You can do it in code too just simply get the childs of root, then childs of admin then the child with the uid. Check out the filtering data part here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data